# Загрузка пакетов через composer в laravel

Tags: laravel, composer, package

Когда устанавливаю пакет в консоли выводится

```
Warning: This development build of composer is over 60 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "w:\modules\php\PHP-7.1-x64\composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version.
Using version ^3.0 for laracasts/flash
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing laracasts/flash (3.0.2): Loading from cache
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
Discovered Package: beyondcode/laravel-dump-server
Discovered Package: cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laracasts/flash
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravelcollective/html
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

Что значат следующие строчки? Раньше их небыло.

```
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
```

Comment: Не переживайте, все хорошо =)

Writing lock file - говорит о том что в файл composer.lock записаны актуальные версии пакетов которые были затянуты композером
Generating optimized autoload files - говорит о том что были сгенеированы классы автоподгрузки.

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump  - выполнение скриптов прописаных в секции composer.json post-cmd-autoload